# Twitter API in android

Tags: android, twitter

I'm a beginner of android and reading a book on android and found that code snippet there

```
twitter = new Twitter("student", "password");
 twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
```

All the post I tweet goes to the site yamba.marakana.com but I don't want to see my twits in that marakana site, I want to post those directly to my twitter account(changing the "student" and "password" field ).

How can I do that? Is it a problem of APIRoouUrl? If yes then let me have the correct URL for the setAPIRootUrl() method.

By the way, I'm using jTwitter API from twitter in Android. Thanks in advance for the repliers :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I think you just need to edit setAPIRootUrl and point to actual Twitter API. Also you should mention the title of the book, some people may have this book and may be able to help you better.

Comment: Name of the book is "Learning Android" by Marko Gargenta!! Let me know what to do now!! Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the video series of the book on Youtube. He mentioned that if you want to post to the actual Twitter site, you have to submit some sort of form to Twitter as a developer for them to give you the proper information. Also, Twitter's API is probably a bit different from that of jTwitter, so it's probably not a good idea when you're just starting to learn.

Comment: Ya!! I also came to know that twitter will provide a submit form which I need to add to my apps to generate the unique id form twitter so that all the users can become unique!! 

I've seen same sort of thing in twitter4j api but in jTwitter I don't know how to authenticate!! Moreover the APIRoot I need to enter is not available! Can you help me with a sample code for jTwitter API so that I can use it to integrate with the twitter?

Thanks for the reply :)